# JTable, tabls cells out of frame (scrollbar) not showing up

Tags: java, swing

I have a Jscrollpane as big as the window of my GUI application, inside this scrollpane I have a gridbaglout showing user dynamically generated tables. if there are a lot of tables the window isn't big enough. hence the scrollpane, some tables are out of the window view, when I scolldown the cells of those tables are not bein displayed. once I click on them they appear.

And when I scroll back up the cells of the top tables also dissappeared, again once I click on them they appear again. and clicked cells do not dissapear if out of sight again.

I have read something about a tablerenderer, but couldn't get it to work or even know if a tablerenderer is what I am looking for.

The code that generates the tables.

```
 //This code is in a for loop the object 'JTable table;' is a private property. 
 //declared at the top of the class, and 'table' is being instanciated in the for loop.
 table = new JTable();
 DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
 model.addColumn(colName,colVal); //colname and val are calculated above -> unnecessary to show.
 table.setModel(model);

 //Table is being added to gridbaglayout, etc...
```

Comment: The table needs to be added in its own JScrollpane

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bit late but found a solution to my problem.

Overytime I scroll I do a repaint and thus the tables get redrawn and won't have empty rows anymore.

```
scrollPane.getViewport().addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
            repaint();
        }
    });
```